# Stretch MVC Web app over whole screen

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm looking for the setting to make a MVC web-app use the whole screen (see red lines in picture). I'll be happy to post some code, but since it looks like this, when a new project is created, I would be posting the out-of-the-box code of a new MVC app.

[image]

The only instance of `body-content`I could find in the whole project is located in the Site.css which looks like this:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `container` and `body-content` classes from the div above jumbotron.

Update:
It's not from the ASP.NET template, it's from Bootstrap:
[image]

Comment: This works find, Thank you. However, I don't get, because `container`and `body-content` only have padding values set. How would I have to change these style get the same behavior?

Comment: One of them also have `max-width`, limiting the width of the jumbotron as well.

If you only want jumbotron to be full-width, you can also take jumbotron div outside and above `container` & `body-content`. That should work too.

Comment: Thats what made me wonder, as I couldn't find anything like max-width in the stylesheet (see updated question). Actually I don't mind the jumbotron, the content is the important part for me.

Answer (score -1):

use `<div class="container-fluid body-content">Blah</div>`